# Generating a 'clean' target for a subdirectory in CMake

Tags: cmake

I want to generate a *clean* target for a subdirectory.

My project structure is like this:

```
app/
  A
  B

lib/
   A
   B
   C
```

Sometimes I want to run clean on just app/A and don't want to clean the library.

Is it possible to tell CMake to generate a *clean* target for each directory?

Or a custom target like *app-clean* which will call clean on each application sub-directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just cd to ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/app/A and run `make clean` there.

Of course, you can add_custom_target(app-A-clean ...) which would do this for you.

```
macro(add_clean_target dir)
add_custom_target(clean-${dir} COMMAND ${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM} clean WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${dir})
endmacro(add_clean_target)
```

Now you can use it in such way:

```
add_clean_target(app-A)
```

Comment: is there any short hand to app-A-clean target for adding add_cutoms_target

Comment: Nope, but i've updated my answer with code snippet. It may need some refinements though.

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer! Is "${CMAKE_BUILD_TOOL} clean" a valid command for every possible value of ${CMAKE_BUILD_TOOL} (which is now used instead of ${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM}) on every platform? Or do we need to differentiate between the different build tools if we want a platform-independent solution?

Comment: Right this isn't gonna work =\ Well, there is no portable way to do such thing, then.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try to set up your CMakeLists.txt to have a [project](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command:project) in each directory, and a "root" CMakeLists.txt which simply does [add_subdirectory](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command:add_subdirectory) for all the sub-projects... then CMake will generate a solution-file or makefile in each project-directory. You can then "step into" such a directory and build and and clean one project.

For example, in one of my projects I have the following structure:

```
projectroot/
  applications/
    appA
  libraries/
    libA
    libB
```

In projectroot I set up a CMakeLists.txt like this:

```
project(MyProject)
add_subdirectory(libraries)
add_subdirectory(applications)
```

In `libraries/`, I do the following:

```
project(Libraries)
add_subdirectory(libA)
add_subdirectory(libB)
add_subdirectory(libC)
```

And then in `applications/`:

```
project(Applications)
add_subdirectory(appA)
```

In this case, I can step into `projectroot/applications/appA` and call `make` or `msbuild appA.sln` and it will start building libA, B, C and then appA. Similarly you can call `make clean` or `msbuild /t:Clean appA.sln`.

The added benefit of an extra directory for all libraries is that I can build them at once by running `make` or `msbuild libraries.sln` in the `libraries/` dir.

Comment: My apologies. Are you working with MSVC? When I wrote the answer I tested it with MinGW but not MSVC. I just tested this again on my MVSC 2010 setup and it indeed cleans the dependencies...

Comment: no . I am on linux and using Make target of cmake. I think it only works for MVSC 2010

Comment: @Vivek: Too bad, then I suggest doing something like arrowdodger: adding a custom clean-target per project. I will keep my answer here "for the record"...