# Dynamically generated source file list for cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

We have a code generator that generates communication protocol definitions into multiple c++ files and want to switch our build system to use cmake.
I have made a sample project to demonstrate the problem we're facing.

The code generator takes an input file and may generate hundreds of
output files so enumerating them in `CMakeLists.txt` is not an option especially since the protocol changes during development. We neither want to use wildcards for this.

We did not find a way to make cmake regenerate the makefiles if one of it's input file changes, according to the documentation it is our belief that `configure_file` should be able to do that but it apparently fails at it's job.

We want the makefile for the main project (in `main` folder in example) to be regenerated by cmake whenever either the generator (in `gen` folder in example) code changes or the protocol definition file (in our example this is `in.txt`) is updated.

I have the following file structure:

```
src
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── gen
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── gen.cpp
├── in.txt
└── main
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── main.cpp
```

with the following contents:
src/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)
project(cmake-config)

add_subdirectory(main)
add_subdirectory(gen)

add_dependencies(main gen run_gen)
```

gen/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)
project(gen)

add_executable(gen gen.cpp)

add_custom_target(
    run_gen
    COMMAND ./gen ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/in.txt
    COMMENT running gen
)

add_dependencies(run_gen gen)
```

gen/gen.cpp:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    ifstream inf(argv[1]);
    ofstream outf("input.txt");
    string word;
    while(inf >> word)
        outf << "set(SOURCES ${SOURCES} " << word << ")\n";

}
```

main/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)
project(main)

if(NOT EXISTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/../gen/input.txt)
    file(WRITE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/../gen/input.txt "") 
endif()

configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/../gen/input.txt ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/input.txt COPYONLY)

set(SOURCES main.cpp)

include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/input.txt)

message(${SOURCES})

add_executable(main ${SOURCES})
```

main/main.cpp:

```
int main(){}
```

`gen` generates `input.txt` using `src/in.txt`. `input.txt` contains a list of source files which I want to use to build `main`:

```
set(SOURCES ${SOURCES} a.cpp)
set(SOURCES ${SOURCES} b.cpp)
set(SOURCES ${SOURCES} c.cpp)
```

We are looking for a solution which does not require bootstrapping `cmake`  or needing to rerun it every time the protocol changes during development. This is easily achievable but undesirable as it leads to problematic code which would end up using older protocol definitions if someone from the team does not realize the protocol file (or generator) has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have found a way to do it. The generator `gen` is put in a separate project, without changing the file structure. `gen` is built and executed when parsing the top level CMakeLists.txt file. When top level `make` is called, it modifies CMakeLists.txt, therefore the next time `make` is called `cmake` runs automatically. Project `gen` has a custom command which regenerates the output if `in.txt` changes.

src/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)
project(cmake-config)

if(NOT EXISTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/gen/Makefile)
    execute_process(COMMAND cmake -B${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/gen -H${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/gen)
endif()
execute_process(COMMAND make -C ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/gen)

add_custom_target(touch_cmakelists.txt ALL
    COMMAND touch ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeLists.txt
)

add_subdirectory(main)
```

gen/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(gen)

add_executable(gen gen.cpp)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/input.txt
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gen ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../in.txt
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gen ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../in.txt
    COMMENT "Running gen"
)

add_custom_target(run_generator ALL
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/input.txt
)
```

main/CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(main)

set(SOURCES main.cpp)

include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/../gen/input.txt)

add_executable(main ${SOURCES})
```

Comment: This seems like essentially the same problem tackled [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36084785/1938798). You may find the discussion there to be a bit more detailed. It takes a similar approach, setting up a sub-build for the generator so it can create the file list for the main build.

Comment: While I'm glad your solution worked for you, it's completely dependent on "touch"ing CMakeLists.txt to force re-configuration (it's not a CMake build-time solution). It might have been useful to tag the question with Linux or MacOS, as touch is not available on Windows.

Comment: @Tanaya if somebody knows any solution on Windows he can share it. I this case more people could benefit from this question than if it were restricted to Linux/MacOs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fully automate the process.
You need a macro that can process a list of file argument.
Here is an example that I use to process interface files for the Zeroc Ice middleware that become source files for the rest of the project.
What you were also missing was the "MAIN_DEPENDENCY" argument of "ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND".

```
macro(sliceCpp outfiles)
    foreach(i ${ARGN})
        GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(name ${i} NAME)
        GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(name2 ${i} NAME_WE)
        SET(infile ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${name})
        SET(out1 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${name2}.cpp)
        SET(out2 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${name2}.h)
        ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
            OUTPUT ${out1} ${out2}
            COMMAND ${ICE_SLICE2CPP}
            ARGS -I${ICE_SLICE_DIR} -I${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} --output-dir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} ${infile}
            MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${infile}
        )
        SET(${outfiles} ${${outfiles}} ${out1} ${out2})
    endforeach(i)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
endmacro(sliceCpp)
```

As a result, CMake will understand the dependencies and only re-build what is necessary. Other frameworks that generate cpp files for interfaces may behave similarly, you may have a look at ROS `generate_messages()` https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/kinetic-devel/clients/roscpp/rosbuild/roscpp.cmake

Comment: Our problem is that we have no file name list when `cmake` is executed. This list is generated by a custom target of the main project and put in input.txt. Initially this file is empty, therefore we want to trigger `cmake` to re-read it.