# Why there are two buttons in GUI Configure and Generate when CLI does all in one command

Tags: cmake, cmake-gui

I understand that cmake is build generator. It mean that it can generate appropriate builds (makefiles, Visual Studio project etc.) based on instructions from CMakeLists.txt. But I do not understand two things which I guess are related:

1. Why there are two buttons "Configure" and "Generate" in cmake-gui? In command line tutorials that I've read (e.g. [this one](http://derekmolloy.ie/hello-world-introductions-to-cmake/)) usual process was done with one `cmake` command.
2. What is cache in cmake world? AFAIK it is state when "Configure" button was pressed but "Generate" button was not pressed. But why is this useful? What all those variables that pops-up after pressing "Configure" mean? Why I'm supposed to edit them? Isn't the only allowed configuration done via CMakeLists.txt?

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are two stages when CMake is run, as reflected by the two buttons in the CMake GUI. The first stage is the *configure* step where the `CMakeLists.txt` file is read in. CMake builds up an internal representation of the project during this stage. After that, the second stage called *generation* occurs where the project files are written out based on that internal representation.

In CMake GUI, the two stages can be run separately. When you run the configure step, the GUI shows all cache variables (see below) which changed their values since the last time configure was run or since CMake GUI was started if this is the first configure run. Normal practice is to re-run the configure stage until no variables are highlighted red. Once configure leaves no variables in red, you can press the generate button and the build tool's native project files will be created and you are good to go starting your builds, etc.

The command line `cmake` tool doesn't allow you to separate out running the configure and generate steps individually. Rather, it always runs configure and then generate.

For simple projects, the distinction between configuration and generation is not all that important. Simple tutorials will often just lump the two together since the reader can get away without understanding the distinction for basic project arrangements. There are, however, some CMake features which rely on this distinction. In particular, [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) are a generation-time feature where decisions about certain aspects of the build are delayed to generation time rather than being fully handled at configure time. One example of this is configuration-specific content such as compiler flags, source files only compiled in for some configurations, etc. The build configuration isn't always known at CMake's configure step (e.g. Xcode and Visual Studio are multi configuration build tools, so there can be more than one and it is selected by the user at build time). The generation step will process generator expressions for each build type and the result can be different for each configuration. You might also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24470998/1938798) informative regarding this particular example. For a more advanced example of a technique which takes advantage of the distinction between configure and generation stages, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36084785/1938798), but be aware it is not a common technique.

Regarding your other question about what is the cache, CMake records information between runs in the variable cache. At the end of the run, it updates a file called `CMakeCache.txt` in the build directory. When you next run CMake, it reads in that cache to pre-populate various things so it doesn't have to recompute them (like finding libraries and other packages) and so that you don't have to supply custom options you want to override each time. You wouldn't typically edit `CMakeCache.txt` by hand (although it's okay to do so). Rather, you can modify the variables you want in CMake GUI and then re-run the configure step (don't forget to then also run generate to create updated project files). You can also define or modify cache variables at the cmake command line with the [`-D` option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for reply. It would be nice to have some practical example (real hello world project) where one can see "Configure" and "Generate" in action and maybe when "red" variables leads to some error during build, don't you know about something? Thanks.

Comment: Red variables are not errors, just things that changed since last time. A specific situation where multiple configure runs may be needed is where one option is only added once some other option is enabled. That's unusual, but perfectly valid. Any project using generator expressions is a practical example where configure and generate matter. I suggest you read up the [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) for more info.