# Creating cmake with wxWidgets

Tags: c++, cmake, wxwidgets, clion

How do I write the cmake file for using wxWidgets in Clion(2021.1 Professionl) in windows 10(20h2)? I tried searching on Google but I couldn't find a thing about it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe see [here](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_cmake.html)
Or this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36572328/getting-started-with-wxwidgets-and-clion)
Or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31092593/how-can-i-use-cmake-to-both-build-wxwidgets-on-demand-and-link-with-it)

Comment: Also see the [minimal example](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/v3.1.4/samples/minimal/CMakeLists.txt).